# 3D graphing the complex values of a function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, graph

This is the real function I am looking to represent in 3D:
**y = f(x) = x^2 + 1**

The complex function would be as follows:
**w = f(z) = z^2 + 1**

Where **z = x + iy** and **w = u + iv**. These are four dimentions (x, y, u, v), but one can use **u** for 3D graphing.

We get:
**f(x + iy) = x^2 + 2xyi - y^2 + 1**

So:
**u = x^2 - y^2 + 1**
and   **v = 2xy**

This **u** is what is being used in the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-100, 101, 150)
y = np.linspace(-100, 101, 150)
 
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
U = (X**2) - (Y**2) + 1

fig = plt.figure(dpi = 300)
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

The following images are the side-view of the 3D function and the 2D plot for reference. I do not think they are alike.

[image]
[image]

Likewise, here is the comparison between the 3 side-view and the 2D plot of w = z^3 + 1. They seem to differ as well.

[image]
[image]

I have not been able to find too many resources regarding plotting in 3D using complex numbers. Because of this and the possible discrepancies mentioned before, I think the code must be flawed, but I can't figure out why. I would be grateful if you could correct me or advise me on any changes.

The inspiration came from Welch Labs' 'Imaginary Numbers are Real' YouTube series where he shows a jaw-dropping representation of the complex values of the function I have been tinkering with.

I was just wondering if anybody could point out any flaws in my reasoning or the execution of my idea since this code would be helpful in explaining the importance of complex numbers to HS students.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `f(z) = z^2 + 1` projection (that is, side-view) looks OK to me.  You can use [this technique](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/2dcollections3d.html) to add the projections; this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

def f(z):
    return z**2 + 1

def freal(x, y):
    return x**2 - y**2 + 1

x = np.linspace(-100, 101, 150)
y = np.linspace(-100, 101, 150)
 
yproj = 0 # value of y for which to project xu axes
xproj = 0 # value of x to project onto yu axes

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = X + 1j * Y
W = f(Z)
U = W.real

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

## surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, U, alpha=0.7)

# xu projection
xuproj = freal(x, yproj)
ax.plot(x, xuproj, zs=101, zdir='y', color='red', lw=5)
ax.plot(x, xuproj, zs=yproj, zdir='y', color='red', lw=5)

# yu projection
yuproj = freal(xproj, y)
ax.plot(y, yuproj, zs=101, zdir='x', color='green', lw=5)
ax.plot(y, yuproj, zs=xproj, zdir='x', color='green', lw=5)

# partially reproduce https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T647CGsuOVU&t=107s
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 150)
y = np.linspace(0, 3, 150)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
U = f(X + 1j*Y).real

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

## surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, U, cmap=cm.jet)
ax.set_box_aspect( (np.diff(ax.get_xlim())[0],
                    np.diff(ax.get_ylim())[0],
                    np.diff(ax.get_zlim())[0]))


#ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

gives this result:

[image: 3d image with x and y projections]

and

[image: Zoom to smaller region near 0, with changed aspect ratio]

The axis ticks don't look very good: you can investigate `plt.xticks` or `ax.set_xticks` (and yticks, zticks) to fix this.

There is a way to visualize complex functions using colour as a fourth dimension; see [complex-analysis.com](https://complex-analysis.com/content/domain_coloring.html) for examples.

Comment: Hello Rory, thank you kindly for taking the time to answer my question. Very interesting. I have been tinkering with your code and I have noticed no changes after deleting the following: 'Z = X + 1j * Y; W = f(Z); U = W.real', so what is its purpose? Also, it bothers me that my graph differs from Welch Labs' (https://youtu.be/T647CGsuOVU?t=107) and that it looks the same regardless of the order of magnitude of the axes - the proportions must stay the same, but I wonder if the image could be made to look 'taller'. I do not know if I am making myself clear. Thanks again Rory. Best, Neil.

Comment: Oops, I had copied your code, and then decided to check if the expression for U and Z.real were the same (they are!).  Thanks.  On your question about making the plot look "taller", I think you mean the aspect ratio; I'll add something that sort-of reproduces the result from that video.

Comment: Thank you again Rory, you are making a difference! I have found out that plotting X and Y against the absolute value of U gives you the roots of the function (purdueEMT: https://youtu.be/WmHs1-hWPNs?t=682), which is in part what I was looking for. Do you know what the difference between the surface created by f(z) (Pringle chip-shaped) and |f(z)| (udder-shaped) is? Which one is the actual surface beyond the confines of a 2D plot (y = f(x))? Thanks again, I am delighted to be making these advances.

Comment: I think you'd have better like with conceptual questions like that on https://math.stackexchange.com/.  I don't have a good answer about the "actual surface".  |f(z)| and Arg f(z) are a 'polar' (radius and angle) alternative to Re f(z) and Im f(z) ("cartesian"); which is better depends on what you're trying to achieve.  If the goal is understanding, look at both forms (and others, too).